# Memoir document class with included non-memoir document

Tags: memoir, standalone

I am creating a LaTeX document (a book) using the Memoir document class. Everything has worked well and I have a nearly-complete book.

I want to include an appendix that contains a LaTeX  document that is typeset using a LaTeX document class that is not the Memoir class, for example, \documentclass[12pt]{report}.

From other LaTeX Stack Exchange answers I gather that the "standalone" package may allow me to do what I need. But those answers are about including tikz pictures (and perhaps non-tikz  pictures, the answers are unclear about this).And the document I want to include is a report with no such pictures and is typeset using a document class that is specialized for a journal.

So, my question is whether "standalone" allows me to do what I need, namely, include a non-memoir class document in an appendix. If so, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance. Best wishes to all.

Comment: can you not simply take the body of the document and set it as a final section of the memoir document? That is the simplest and likely to give the best results

Comment: otherwise you could include the whole document as is using `\includepdf` but then has the original page numbers and formatting

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll try the second one: it is what I need. I want to retain the original formatting (the document is  a published journal paper). I think the first suggestion would typeset the document in Memoir style.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that using \includepdf does not work for me. It works technically, that is, it does insert the pdf  document. But for publishing reasons, I need to include the LaTeX source for the document and let LaTeX do the typesetting live, so to speak. This is what I understand the "standalone" package does. So I'm back to "standalone". What I am asking the LaTeX community is to tell me about their "standalone" experience inserting documents that are not graphics and to provide sample LaTeX code for doing so. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have to provide the LaTeX code(s) in a single file then try using the `filecontents` environment in the preamble where the contents of the environment is the code of your report document. When running LaTeX on the main document the `filecontents` will be made into a separate file which can then be processed by LaTeX to produce the PDF to be included in the main document.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, this is very interesting. I'll give it a try and report back.